# How to reference a content-region block in node template?

Tags: 6, theming, blocks

Scenario:

I have a basic node content type that has some fields. I also have a custom block that will appear in the content-region of this node content type.

How can I (is it possible) reference the rendering of the block from within the theme node--mycontenttype.tpl.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 6, you can do something like this:

```
$block=module_invoke(MODULE_NAME, 'block', 'view', BLOCK_NAME);
```

and now `$block['content']` will contain the html content of BLOCK_NAME defined within MODULE_NAME.

I just noticed the -- in your template name, so in Drupal 7 it would be:

```
$block=module_invoke(MODULE_NAME, 'block_view', BLOCK_NAME);
```

and more details can be found [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7).

Comment: This worked perfectly, exact solution to my problem. Thanks a ton!